# automatically insert extracted variable for further coding in intellij or eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I do this a lot, | is where the caret is:

```
new MyClass()|
```

then I press

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

which is the same as extract variable. Then I enter the name of the variable.
Now i get this

```
$myEnteredVariableName = new MyClass();|
```

guess what? I want to use the variable
So i have to go to the beginning of the line, copy the whole variable by first selecting, and then moving on with actually coding. Is there no way to speed this up?

e.g. what I really want to get is:

```
$myEnteredVariableName = new MyClass();
$myEnteredVariableName|
```

is there something for this in eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to use the variable` and what language are you developing in?.. cause in java you'd get something along the lines of `MyClass myEnteredVariableName = new MyClass();`

Comment: @Grove how many times do you create a local variable, and then, not use it? honestly, you will always do something like:
`$myEnteredVariableName->executeFunction();` or the equivalent in java `myEnteredVariableName.executeFunction()` so creating a local variable but not having the template create the variable for further executing is just plain bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse (and at least for java) just unselect the created statment with the left arrow press Ctrl+Space then the first hit of the content assist will be the newly created variable.

Comment: for php one has to write `$` and then the first hit